# Meaning of @GeneratedValue with strategy of TABLE

Tags: jpa, primary-key

The JPA specification gives the following explanation of the annotation `@GeneratedValue(strategy=TABLE)`:

> The `TABLE` generator type value indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using an underlying database table to ensure uniqueness.

But what does "using an underlying database table" mean in practice? Does it mean using an auxiliary table? Or by scanning the entity-table to find an ID not in use? Or something else?

Comment: An answer by http://stackoverflow.com/users/416206/james, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10091167/545127, says "only every 100 inserts will lock the row **in the sequence table**", suggesting use of an auxiliary table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [JavaDoc for `TableGenerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html), it has a nice example of how it works:

Example 1:

```
@Entity public class Employee {
    ...
    @TableGenerator(
        name="empGen", 
        table="ID_GEN", 
        pkColumnName="GEN_KEY", 
        valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE", 
        pkColumnValue="EMP_ID", 
        allocationSize=1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=TABLE, generator="empGen")
    int id;
    ...
}
```

Example 2:

```
@Entity public class Address {
    ...
    @TableGenerator(
        name="addressGen", 
        table="ID_GEN", 
        pkColumnName="GEN_KEY", 
        valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE", 
        pkColumnValue="ADDR_ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=TABLE, generator="addressGen")
    int id;
    ...
}
```

Basically `ID_GEN` is an internal (non-business) table of key-value pairs. Every time JPA wants to generate ID it queries that database:

```
SELECT GEN_VALUE
FROM ID_GEN
WHERE GEN_KEY = ...
```

and incremenets the `GEN_VALUE` column. This mechanism can be used to emulate sequences or to take even further control of generated ids.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of EclipseLink, it uses an auxiliary table. [The documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/GeneratedValue) says

> By default, EclipseLink chooses the `TABLE` strategy using a table named `SEQUENCE`, with `SEQ_NAME` and `SEQ_COUNT` columns