# How to insert check considering system date + five years in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL Workbench and want to create a table with a field "finaldate".

When the user is filling that field "finaldate", the database should check, **if the finaldate does not exceed the current (system date) plus five years**.

e.g.: for today, 11th of December **2014**, only values of finaldate should be okay, that are not higher then 11th of December **2019**.

Anyone an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL doesn't have data constraints like this. All it has are unique constraints and foreign key constraints. This should be done in the client application.

Comment: Check out the following for one way to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254229/mysql-check-constraint-with-date

Answer (score 2):

Having MySQL do something in reaction to a SQL Statement is called a trigger:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

To do the math on checking whether the date is more than 5 years in the future, refer to this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: Beat me to it. Triggers is the way to go. Example: http://blog.christosoft.de/2012/08/mysql-check-constraint/